# Type D German Visa, 90/180 rule

Tags: visas, 90-180-visa-rules

I am an **Indian in Germany**. I have a **type D visa** that says **'Deutschland'** and its validity is from **1.4.19 to 31.8.19 ( 5 months). I don't have a resident permit, and I am in Germany only for a semester-long student exchange program.**
I wanted to know **if I can travel to other Schengen states in July and August**. It's said there is a 90/180 rule with this visa, so I can travel to Schengen states other than Germany upto 90 days in any 180 day period. But, when do my 90 days start; do they start on the day I entered Germany or do they start when I step out of Germany into another Schengen state? Super confused over here and any help will be appreciated, since my travel plans are frozen because of this! Thanks!

Comment: The only days you count toward the 90 are days when you are in some Schengen country other than Germany.

Comment: Your time in Germany **does not count** for the Schengen 90 day 'clock'. The clock will be on 'hold' during the time in Germany.